# How to pass R-value to function as const

Tags: c++

I want to know how to pass r-value as const parameter to function.
For example..

```
int func(const int* num)
{
   return *num * 2;
}

int main()
{
   int a = 3;
   int result = func(&a);
   return 0;
}
```

In this case, result is 6 and it works totally fine.
But I don't want to make temporary variable, I just want to make it simple.

```
int main()
{
   int result = fun(3);
   return 0;
}
```

I know this is very silly but is there any way that I can make this work?

Comment: pass the argument by value?

Comment: Or let the function take the object by const renference (`const int&`). Then it'll be able to handle both l-value and r-value references. But for primitives it's almost always better to pass by value.

Comment: i dont understand the question. In the first part you are passing a pointer, in the second not so you just have to change the argument accordingly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you cannot change `func` to take by value or by const reference,

a one liner can be done:

```
int result = fun([](const auto&& e){ return &e; }(3));
```

You can turn the lambda in utility function:

```
template <typename T>
const T* address_of_temporary(const T&& t) { return &t; }
```

```
int result = fun(address_of_temporary(3));
```

Comment: Is it ok to use the returned address after the temporary is destroyed? This doesn't look safe to me.

Comment: @Cem: temporary is destroyed at end of full expression (here after result has its value), so it is correct. Return value of `address_of_temporary` should indeed not be stored for "future" reused (that's why [`std::addressof`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/addressof) has deleted overload for temporary).

Comment: Thank you, I thought they were destroyed the moment the function returns. Now it makes sense.

Answer (score 4):

Pass by value:

```
int func(const int num)
{
   return num * 2;
}
```

The `const` doesn't affect the caller at all, it just means you can't change `num` inside the function.  Most people would omit it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! The 'func' function is just an example, I actually wanna apply this to API function. so I cannot change functions at all. Is there any way that I can do this without changing function?

Comment: No. If you can't change the code you can't change the code's behavior.

Answer (score -1):

You can achieve it like this without unnecessary copies

```
#include <iostream>

int func(const int&& num)
{
   return num * 2;
}

int main()
{
   int result = func(3);
   return 0;
}
```

and if you don't want to change the function then you have to pass the address which you can't get from temp value , without adding more code

Comment: @Tomson hope it solves your optimization issue

Comment: That rvalue reference is pointless, right?

Comment: not clear what "optimization issue" this solves

Comment: in question he  don't want to create a temporary variable which seems to be a and he is not using it right.

Comment: it's not about optimization issue , the variable a =3 is required only if the function in accepting a pointer. and is  and never used again. it's a waste

Comment: @Kubahasn'tforgottenMonica it will implement move semantics ,  I think it will be better than having a variable passed which again is never used